# Group by columns and join row values of another two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to group data by all columns in my dataframe, with the exception of 2.

In the example below, I'm trying group by `col1` and `col2`

For `col3`, where `col1` & `col2` values match, join the `col3` values using `;`. For `col4`, do much the same, expect join with a `\n`

Hopefully the basic example gives a better example of what I'm trying to do.

**Current Dataframe:**

```
col1  col2    col3   col4
001   time    yes    working
001   time    no     resting
002   time    no     flying
003   hours   yes    flying
002   time    no     flying
003   lights  no     flying
```

**What I want:**

```
 col1  col2   col3      col4
 001   time   yes ; no  working \n resting
 002   time   no ; no   flying \n walking
 003   hours  yes       flying
 003   lights  no     flying
```

The below seems to work for each column (`col3` and `col4`). But I'm not not sure what code I need for this to work for both columns to produce the desired output.

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
new_df = df.groupby(cols)['col3'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x)).reset_index()

cols = ['col1', 'col2']
new_df = df.groupby(cols)['col4'].apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Comment: You are looking for `.agg` instead of apply

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) (if necessary) with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
cols1 = ['col3','col4']
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(cols+cols1).groupby(cols)[cols1].agg('\n'.join).reset_index()
print (new_df)
  col1    col2       col3                col4
0  001    time  no \n yes  working \n resting
1  002    time         no              flying
2  003   hours        yes              flying
3  003  lights         no              flying
```

Or use `set`s for unique values per each column for separately:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
cols1 = ['col3','col4']
new_df = df.groupby(cols)[cols1].agg(lambda x: '\n'.join(set(x))).reset_index()
print (new_df)
  col1    col2       col3                col4
0  001    time  no \n yes  working \n resting
1  002    time         no              flying
2  003   hours        yes              flying
3  003  lights         no              flying
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. Although I was hoping there would be a way to use `\n` as the separator for col4 instead of `;`. Could you also explain why `agg` is working and not `apply`?

Comment: @AaronWright - Because `groupby.agg` working with each column separately

Answer (score 0):

pivot_table can also be an option

```
df.pivot_table(index=["col1","col2"],values=["col3","col4"],aggfunc={"col3":lambda x:" ; ".join(x.astype(str)),
                                                                    "col4":lambda x:" \n ".join(x.astype(str))}).reset_index()
```

output:

```
    col1    col2    col3        col4
0   001     time    yes ; no    working \n resting
1   002     time    no ; no     flying \n flying
2   003     hours   yes         flying
3   003     lights  no          flying
```